# scanf() not working correctly within for loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, input, scanf

I am attempting to store multiple strings from stdin into a temporary variable.

Each string will be entered following a new line character.

This is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        char string;
        scanf("%s\n", &string);
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }
}
```

The for loop does not run  as intended, it only loops twice, seems scanf is interfering with the loop.

stdin:

```
test
test
```

stdout:

```
7631717
```

Is there a way to store input/each line from stdin dynamically into a `char` variable without a fixed size/length?

Comment: Always check the number of items successfully scanned.  That is, you *must* check the return value of scanf.  Always.  If a call to scanf is not on the RHS of an assignment, it is a bug.

Comment: Except perhaps in a situation like `while ( scanf(...) == ...`, so my claim about being on the RHS of an assignment is hyperbole.  But you must check the return value!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to not be limited to a given size reading a string you can use the modifier 'm' :

```
char * p;

if (scanf("%ms", &p) == 1) {
  ...use p;
  free(p); /* when stop to be usefull
}
```

From the man of  `scanf` :

> An optional 'm' character.  This is used with string conversions (%s, %c, %[),  and
> relieves  the  caller  of  the  need to allocate a corresponding buffer to hold the
> input: instead, scanf() allocates a buffer of  sufficient  size,  and  assigns  the
> address  of  this  buffer  to the corresponding pointer argument, which should be a
> pointer to a char * variable (this variable does not need to be initialized  before
> the call).  The caller should subsequently free(3) this buffer when it is no longer
> required.

The previous way allows to red a 'word', to read a full line removing spaces (' ', newline, tab ...) at the beginning:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char * p;

  if (scanf(" %m[^\n]", &p) == 1) {
    printf("'%s'\n", p);
    free(p);
  }
  else
    puts("error (EOF...)");
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
/tmp % gcc -Wall c.c
/tmp % ./a.out
    aze qsd
'aze qsd'
/tmp % ./a.out < /dev/null
error (EOF...)
/tmp %
```

If you do not have that modifier (not posix ...) to read a full line as it is you can do :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char * p = malloc(1);
  size_t len = 0;
  int c;
  
  while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF)) {
    p = realloc(p, len+1);
    if (p == NULL) {
      puts("not enough memory");
      return -1;
    }
    p[len++] = c;
  }
  p[len] = 0;
  
  printf("'%s'\n", p);
  free(p);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
/tmp % gcc -Wall c.c
/tmp % ./a.out
  aze qsd
'  aze qsd'
/tmp % ./a.out < /dev/null
''
/tmp %
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know about the `m` modifier in `scanf()` and a good example of using it in various situations.

Comment: +1 for `m`; did not know it (and still cannot find it in the C standard (e.g. this online draft http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Contents)?

Comment: `m` isn't a part of C standard - but available in POSIX standard. So if you're on a non-POSIX system, you have to look at alternatives.

Comment: @RohanBari I edited my answer to add an other example

Comment: Limitations.`scanf(" %m[^\n]", &p)` does not "store input/each line from stdin" when the line consists only of white space.  Instead they are silently consumed.  Further, lead white-space of a line are not saved.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica sure, this the goal of the space before '%'

Comment: @P.P yes, that can be done 'by hand', I edited my answer, thank you for the remark

Comment: @StephanLechner yes, this is probably why it is not often used, and why it is the first time I speak about it in an answer on S.O. (if I remember well) ^^

Answer (score 2):

`char string;` is not a string but a single character. Reading in a string with format `%s` into a single character is undefined behaviour as soon as you enter at least one character. This is because the string termination character will be appended, too.

Write ...

```
char string[100];
scanf("%99s", string);
```

and everything should be fine.

BTW: If you intend to read in complete lines (including white spaces at the beginning, in between and at the end), consider using `fgets` instead of `scanf`.

Comment: Is there a method to get the input dynamically, without a fixed size/length?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to store input/each line from stdin dynamically into a char variable without a fixed size/length?

If willing to going the POSIX route, use [`getline()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) to "store input/each line from stdin dynamically".

Lop off the potential trailing new-line if desired

```
       char *line = NULL;
       size_t len = 0;
       ssize_t nread;

       while ((nread = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1) {
           if (nread > 0 && line[nread-1] == '\n') line[--nread] = 0;
           printf("Retrieved line of length %zu: <%s>\n", nread, line);
       }

       free(line);
```

I suspect `nread > 0 && line[nread-1] == '\n'` can be reduced to `line[nread-1] == '\n'` as I see not case where `nread` returns 0.